# Who is the subject of Bilaam's prophecy?

Tags: messiah, king-david, parashat-balak, bilam

The gentile prophet Bilaam says:

> [I] heard the words of God, and know the knowledge of the most High, [and] saw the vision of the Almighty... I see him, but not now; what I behold will not be soon: A star shall shoot forth out of Jacob, and a scepter shall rise out of Israel… A ruler shall come out of Jacob... [Numbers 24:12-19]

This passage is understood by most commentators to refer to the future Messiah. Most, but not all.  In commenting on Numbers 24:17, Ibn Ezra said:

> It appears to me that this prophecy refers to King David.

Now, Isaiah [9:5-6, 11:1-13] clearly refers to the Messiah.  But Isaiah does not tie his prophecy to Bilaam's.  (Does he?)  So on what grounds do we conclude that Bilaam refers to the Messiah and not somebody else, King David being a prime candidate?  (Or are they considered one and the same since the Messiah will descend from David?)

Comment: Could be both. A prophecy with multiple messages for different generations.

Comment: The prophecy refers to a single individual.

Comment: I don't find that contradictory to my previous statement.